# eclipse dark theme menu

Tags: eclipse, gtk, themes

I'm using i3 with the default config and no gtk theme (most gtk apps are dull gray and that's fine) however, eclipse's Dark theme has a small problem with the menu bar:

[image]

the menu text color and background are too close and it's hard to read. Is there anyway to override that somewhere? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You may change the css file used by the theme. Go to:

```
ECLIPSE_HOME\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.themes_versionNumber\css
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried having a look at the css files and I found the #org-eclipse-ui-main-toolbar class in e3-dark.css, I tried setting the color attribute to #FFFFFF but it didn't do anything. Any idea where the actual menubar class is? Thanks

Comment: I too experienced the same problem and had to resort to the solution from @Funkensieper. Supposing I have done it right, editing the CSS file hasn't worked. Even though it is "working", I'd prefer a better solution than using the old GTK. The overall graphic doesn't look nice.

Answer (score 0):

Try running Eclipse with GTK2 flag:

```
export SWT_GTK3=0
./eclipse
```

See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=436753#c1 .